# Firebase Retrieving and passing data to variable

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

[ridvankucuk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4rUl.png)  [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntxrq.png)

```
func getHandleStatus() -> String {
    var handle = String()
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("status").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let status = snapshot.value["status"] as? Int {
            if status == 0 {
                //print(snapshot.key)
                handle = snapshot.key
            } else {
                print("NO")
            }
        }
    })
    return handle
}
```

When i return "handle", its always empty string. I set the variable "handle = snapshot.key" and when i return, its still empty. Please help.

Comment: You need to understand asynchronous processing. The call to `return handle` happens long before the block is executed.

Comment: I'm super new to this and if you can show me light on basic, it will really help me.

Comment: and thank you for the quick reply

Comment: how can i return "return" only after the block is complete?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your method is async and it is not waiting the main thread. So writing return makes no sense. You should do something else.
Define a variable outside of the function such as:

```
var handle: String? = nil {
        didSet{
            // You know handle is set now
        }
    }
```

And update your getHandleStatus method:

```
func getHandleStatus(){
    var handle = String()
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("status").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let status = snapshot.value["status"] as? Int {
            if status == 0 {
                //print(snapshot.key)
                self.handle = snapshot.key
            } else {
                print("NO")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I've added an image to the post. Thats where I'm stuck at. :(

Comment: In the didSet method you know that handle is setted. You can do whatever you want with the handleId.

Comment: i print it out with print(handlerID). The error state its nil.

Comment: Are you sure that snapshot.key is not nil? Put a breakpoint into didSet method also and check it.

Comment: snapshot.key is "1234". I've print it out in the block. Its not nil.

Comment: I've attach another photo. It has data "1234"